# gRsync set permissions same as when copying

Tags: mount, permissions, samba, music, rsync

I am having trouble with permissions when using gRsync. The reason I am using grsync is it seems a lot easier to use my mounted windows share when using the browse feature. Currently I'm not sure how to get to my windows share through the terminal.

The setup:

I have a windows 10 computer (named "flat") with a shared folder called "completed" this folder is filled with music in the structure of completed>albumfolder>song. My intent is to use my ubuntu computer to rsync and pull the files from this "completed" folder and place them into a folder on my ubuntu computer. These files are intended to be used with subsonic (software that allows you to stream your own music library). Subsonic uses a user that was created without a home folder called "subsonic". Currently what I have noticed is if I copy the files from the mounted windows share just using nautlius the subsonic software will see both the files (songs) and the folders (album folders). However if I run grsync the file permissions some how get messed up and the subsonic software can only see the folders (album folders) and cannot see the songs themselves.

The problem:

When I run a grsync with no settings having to do with permissions everything seems to go good but when I check on the songs inside of the album folders they seem to have different permissions from what I would get if I just mounted the windows folder in nautilus and then copied all the files.

The permissions for the album folders seems to be the same between rsync and copying but the songs within the folders end up with different permissions based on what method I end up choosing.

The permissions when copying look like:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kv kv 5691435 May 10 2012 01 - Song title.flac
```

The permissions when running rsync look like:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 kv kv 5691435 May 10 2012 01 - Song title.flac
```

The source looks like:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=flat,share=completed/
```

My goal is to get rsync to end up with the same permissions as if I just copied them. Currently if I run rsync subsonic can see the folders but not the songs. If I copy however subsonic can see the folders and the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**rsync** has an option to keep permission

```
 -p, --perms                 preserve permissions
```

If you use gRsync, the same option is under Basic Options tab, mine is in spanish and looks like this:

[gRsync Basic Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icQZr.png)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess I always took this to mean that permissions would be kept how they are on windows. Meaning none of my ubuntu users would even have permissions to the file. Am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Comment: I tried it out and you are right, that is what I was looking for. I still noticed that the permissions are -rwxrwxr-r-- instead of -rw-rw-r-- not sure why that is. Also if you could possibly clarify/answer my question in the above comment that would be awesome.

Comment: gRsync uses your own linux user, or root if you enable it on Additional options tab. I think that isn't your problem. The only difference there was +execution permission.

Comment: the windows file system is mounted by network (samba) or attached Hard drive, maybe the problem is how you mount the Windows  file system

Comment: I was kind of thinking that might be the problem. I will look into figuring out a proper mounting setup for the windows share. Thank you for everything.